# OracleSQL - Select ALL columns with DISTINCT on one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and am trying to get all columns returned when querying for distinct values on a particular column.  I've tried using other answers I've found on here but I am not getting as many results as expected.

Here is the distinct field query (returns 3203 results):

```
select distinct name
from relationships;
```

My attempt based on other answers I found here on SO (returns 2071 results):

```
select *
from (
   select relationships.*, row_number() 
   over (partition by name order by dbms_random.random) 
   as row_number 
   from relationships
   ) relationships
where row_number = 1;
```

So since there is such a large discrepancy between the two queries and how many results I'm getting, I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Multiple values may exist in other columns for the same value in your distinct column. How would you choose which values to display in those other columns? Based on your 2nd example, looks like you just want to pick one randomly?

Comment: ... which should work with what you've shown. What data type is `name`? And is `relationships` a table or a view? Can you identify anything about the names which appear in one list but not the other? You could `minus` those two queries (if you change the second one to `select name`) and see what is left. (And what version and patch level of Oracle are you using?)

Comment: @AlexPoole `name` is a `VARCHAR2(360 BYTE)`. `relationships` is a table. The versions are... Oracle Database 12c Enterprise 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Those _exact_ queries, as you posted, return 3203 and 2071 rows, respectively, when you run them in your database?  Or, are the queries you posted simplified/modified somehow from what you are actually running?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak yep, running those exact queries in my database using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm also on 12.1.0.2.0 and can't replicate your issue. Tried on a name field in a table with ~50k distinct names including nulls. Does your total change if you replace `dbms_random.random` with `rowid`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem either.

```
SQL> create table mytable as select object_name, object_type from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytable select object_name, null from dba_objects;

22491 rows created.

SQL> select count(*) from mytable;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     44982

SQL> select count(*) from (select distinct object_name from mytable );

  COUNT(*)
----------
     15701

SQL> select count(*)
  2  from (
  3     select mytable.*, row_number()
  4     over (partition by object_name order by dbms_random.random)
  5     as row_number
  6     from mytable
  7     ) mytable
  8  where row_number = 1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     15701
```

So something weird is going on here. Are you running these queries from the same session; you don't have two sessions going and one has uncommitted changes?

I'd create tables based on your two queries and look for differences between them. Like:

```
create table tab1 as select distinct name from relationships;
```

If this problem is really happening, there should be rows in one table that are not in the other.